# Python jmespath: check key and nested key in the same query?

Tags: python, json, jmespath

The data is

```
data_case_c = {
    "qualities": {
        "id": "0123456789",
        "key_criteria": "Target",
        "desired_value": {"id": "987654321", "label": "CORRECT"},
    }
}
```

I want to check that `key_criteria` is `Target`. And if it is, also check that `desired_value[label]` is `CORRECT`.

Here is the query I thought might work

```
query = "qualities.key_criteria == 'Target' | qualities.desired_value.label == 'CORRECT'"
```

It returns False, which is incorrect for what I want since `qualities.key_criteria` equals `Target` and `qualities.desired_value.label` equals `CORRECT`

This returns True.

```
query = "qualities.key_criteria == 'Target'"
```

Basically I guess I need to get the `qualities` object passed to the next expression when the first evaluates to `True`. How do I do that?

Comment: Oh, looks like it's just a combination of expressions via AND/&&